# Where clause in group by and counts

Tags: mysql

In the below query, the value of cnt is only calculated based on the number of rows selected. (Where id < 10)

I want it to count the entire table and only insert the first 10 rows from that table based on a count from the entire table.

So if John Smith San Diego California appears on rows 11 and 55 it needs to take that into account in the count.

I tried moving the WHERE clause but that gives an error.

```
INSERT INTO matchNewCounts(`uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, 
`middle`, `last`, `counter`, `city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2` , `cnt`)
SELECT `uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, `middle`, `last`, 
`counter`,`city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2`, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM matchNewIndex
where id < 10 
GROUP BY `first`, `last`, `city`, `state`
```

Sample:
Row < 10

John Smith San Diego California

John Smith San Diego California

Row > 10

John Smith San Diego California

Expected results the count must be 3.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` query is invalid, because you only include 4 columns, but select more than those 4 columns.  Some sample data might help you get an answer here.

Comment: Have you tried LIMIT instead of WHERE??

Comment: update  your question and add  a clear data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It executes when I run it here.

Comment: @scaisEdge I added the expected results

Comment: @AlexYeskov I car can still sometimes drive with a flat tire, but that doesn't mean that the driver should not be worried about the state of his car.  Even if your query _runs_, it doesn't make any sense.  Research only full group by mode in MySQL to learn more about your question, and how to fix it.

Comment: @nacho Limit works and gives the expected answer! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexYeskov i will put it as an answer su you can accept it

Comment: @nacho I really wouldn't bother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use LIMIT instead of WHERE

```
INSERT INTO matchNewCounts(`uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, 
    `middle`, `last`, `counter`, `city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2` , `cnt`)
SELECT `uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, `middle`, `last`, 
    `counter`,`city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2`, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM matchNewIndex
GROUP BY `first`, `last`, `city`, `state`
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you need only the first 10 rows based on id. Your query should have `HAVING` clause.So,if the `names` are not in a sequence order the result will get generated based on `name`order rather than by id.

```
INSERT INTO matchNewCounts(`uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, 
    `middle`, `last`, `counter`, `city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2` , `cnt`)
SELECT `uniqueidentifier`, `fullName`, `first`, `middle`, `last`, 
    `counter`,`city`, `state`, `cit2`, `state2`, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM matchNewIndex
GROUP BY `first`, `last`, `city`, `state`
HAVING id<10;
```